# Rails GET request model update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Say i have a `GET`request action called `thankyou` that redirects the user to the `thankyou` template after they have ordered and paid for an item. In said action, is it bad practice, since it's a `GET` request for me to update some attribute on the order?

e.g.

```
def thankyou
    @order.update_attributes(:approval_required => true)
end
```

Comment: the problem is that anyone can trigger that update. Either make it a POST, or make the thank you per order with a parameter

Comment: thanks, what do you mean 'make the thank you per order with a parameter'?

Comment: something like a url of /thankyou?token=234776qsgr5avzsvr so you know that it is for that order. But if your thankyou page is generic, make it GET, and update the order's attributes in the appropriate place (probably the payment processor callback action), which will then can render a thankyou page

Comment: ok cool, so my GET request path to the thankyou will look like this `get 'checkout/:id.:customer_id.:hash/thankyou' => 'order_tracking#thankyou'`....that should be sufficient?